# Как парсить XML

Tags: delphi, xml

Имеется XML примерно такого вида:

```
...
    <positions>
        <position>
            <Info>
                <Number>1000</Number>
            </Info>
        </position>
        <position>
            <Info>
                <Number>1001</Number>
            </Info>
        </position>
        <position>
            <Info>
                <Number>1001</Number>
            </Info>
        </position>
        ...
    </positions>
    <specials>
        ...
        <special>        
            <publications>
                ...
                <publication>
                    <Number>5000</Number>
                </publication>
                ...
            </publications>
        </special>

        ...
    </specials>
...
```

Никак не могу сообразить как получить только **number** из (**positions->postion->info->number**).
Пробовал так:

```
var
  XMLDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  Nodes: IXMLDOMNodeList;
begin
      XMLDoc := CoDOMDocument.create;
      try

        XMLDoc.Async := false;
        XMLDoc.Load(MyXML);

        Nodes := XMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName('Number');

        for i := 0 to Nodes.Length - 1 do
        begin
          SynMemo1.Lines.Add((Nodes.Item[i] as IXMLDOMNode).Text)
        end;
      finally
        XMLDoc := nil;
      end;
end;
```

Но возвращаются все **Number**, а мне нужны только из **positions->postion->info->number**

Comment: Используйте ф-цию `selectNodes` и изучите xpath запросы.

Comment: Смог получить только так: Nodes := XMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName('Info/Number');

Comment: Вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406138/finding-elements-with-xpath-in-delphi

Comment: @Kromster не надо так, для этих целей есть XPath запросы, которыми можно запросто получить нужную коллекцию или элемент из XML документа без всяких переборов и тонн кода.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci а ладно, плюсану оба ответа и удалю коменты - от них пользы щас уже нет)

Answer (score 2):

Вот вариант, как добираться до нужных значений вложенными циклами. Структура не полная, поэтому написал примерно. Должно быть понятно, как получить нужные значения:

```
var
    Xml: IXmlDocument;
    Root: IXmlNode;
    Index, Jndex: Integer;
    NodePositions: IXmlNode;
begin
    Xml := TXmlDocument.Create(nil);
    try
        Xml.LoadFromFile('filename');
        Root := Xml.DocumentElement;
        for Index := 0 to Root.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
        begin
            if LowerCase(Root.ChildNodes[Index].NodeName) = 'positions'
            then begin
                NodePositions := Root.ChildNodes[Index];

                ...

                for Jndex := 0 to NodePositions.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
                    if LowerCase(NodePositions.ChildNodes[Jndex].NodeName) = 'number'
                    then Memo.Lines.Add(VarToStrDef(NodePositions.ChildNodes[Jndex].NodeValue, ''));

                ...
            end;
        end;
    finally
        Xml := nil;
    end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам достаточно составить правильный [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms256471(v=vs.85).aspx) запрос:

```
var
  XMLDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  Nodes: IXMLDOMNodeList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  XMLDoc := CoDOMDocument.create;
  try
    ...
    XMLDoc.Load(MyXML);

    // все элементы 'number' внутри 'info' и т.д. до элементов 'positions', которые
    // могут быть в любом месте документа 
    Nodes := XMLDoc.documentElement.SelectNodes('//positions/postion/info/number');

    for i := 0 to Nodes.Length - 1 do
      ...

  finally
    XMLDoc := nil;
  end;
end;
```

И не нужно парсить документ вручную или перебирать вложенными циклами. Используйте готовые инструменты. Посмотрите [примеры составления XPath запросов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms256086(v=vs.85).aspx).